# tabu package \end{tabu} error

Tags: tables, tabu

ShareLaTex is 'finding' several errors occurring at the line `\end{tabu}`
I'm fairly new to latex and I'm struggling to spot what the problem is.

Any help would be appreciated, here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{316 SS comp.}
\label{tab:316}
\rowcolors{1}{blue!5!white!95}{white}
\begin{tabu} to \textwidth {X[.2,l] X[.1,l] X[l]}
\rowfont\bfseries {{Element} & {wt\%} & {Isotopic Abundance}} \\[0.20em]
\small{Chromium} & 17.00 & \ce{^{52} Cr}(83.76\%),\ce{^{53} Cr}(9.55\%),\ce{^{50} Cr}(4.31\%),\ce{^{54} Cr}(2.38\%) \\[0.2em]
\\etc.....

\end{tabu}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the braces in the title row spanning multiple columns:

```
\rowfont\bfseries {Element} & {wt\%} & {Isotopic Abundance} \\[0.20em]
```